# Example of functions that are continuous on irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I solved the problem below in Terence tao's book. I don't understand the intuition of this problem.

I couldn't also prove part (c). 
I proved $f_n(x)$ is continuous and $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$.

Here is my work. Assume $x_n \rightarrow x$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n^{\prime}}(x_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \Sigma_{r \in \mathbb{Q}: r < x_n, g(r) \geq 2^{-n^{\prime}}} g(r) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n^{\prime}}(x_n) =  \Sigma_{r \in \mathbb{Q}: r < \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x, g(r) \geq 2^{-n^{\prime}}} g(r) = f_{n^{\prime}}(x).$$

It is easy to see that $|f(x) - f_n(x)| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at "the Devil's staircase."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

It is a simpler version of the function described above, but has many of the same properties.

Let $x_0$ be an irrational number.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N > 0$ such that $n>N \implies |g(q(n))| < \frac {\epsilon}{2}$

And $\sum_\limits {n = N}^\infty g(q(n)) < \epsilon$

There are only finitely many $n\le N$

Let $q(m)$ be the member of the subset that is closest to $x_0$

$\delta = |x_0-q(m)|$

Then, when $|x-x_0| < \delta, |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$